# Fast test execution in a playframework fake application

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2, specs2

Running tests as described [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaFunctionalTest)

```
"Spec" should {
  "example" in new WithApplication {
    ...
  }
}
```

is unacceptably slow for me. This is because new WithApplication is starting and stoping framework at every example. Don't get me wrong, a framework itself loads very fast, but if database is configured (surprise!), situation becomes terrible.

Here are some measurments:

```
"The database layer" should {

  "test1" in  {
    1 must be equalTo(1)
  }
  ...
  "test20" in {
    1 must be equalTo(1)
  }
}
```

Execution time: **2 seconds**. Same test with WithApplication at every example consumes **9 seconds**

I was able to achive much better results thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10013852/316563)

```
import play.api.Play
import play.api.test.FakeApplication
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import scalikejdbc._

class MySpec extends Specification {

var fake: FakeApplication = _

step {fake = FakeApplication(...)}
step {Play.start(fake)}

"The database layer" should {

  "some db test" in {
    DB localTx { implicit session =>
      ...
    }
  }

  "another db test" in {
    DB localTx { implicit session =>
      ...
    }
  }

  step {Play.stop()}
}
```

}

Pros: performance boost

Cons:

- need to copy-paste setup and tear-down code because don't know how to
  reuse it (by reuse I mean something like "class MySpec extends
  Specification **with NoWasteOfTime**"
- new WithApplication() calls Helpers.running which looks like this

```
synchronized {
  try {
    Play.start(fakeApp)
    block
  } finally {
    Play.stop()
    play.api.libs.ws.WS.resetClient()
  }
}
```

so I can't completely emulate Helpers.running behaviour (resetClient is not visible for my code) without reflection.

Please suggest how to break cons or different approach how accomplish my issue.

Comment: Do you want to setup/teardown once for a specification, or do you want to do it for every test within it?

Comment: It's too bad that it's 18 months later and Play still hasn't changed this behaviour. Starting the app for each test is ludicrous. Play 3 will have DI that will hopefully remove the need for a running app altogether.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if it is the best possible solution but in this thread:
[Execute code before and after specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16936811/execute-code-before-and-after-specification)

You can read a solution for reusable code. I implemented it with little modifications. For me the beforeAll step did not run and added the `sequential` modifier.

```
import org.specs2.mutable._
import org.specs2.specification._

class PlayAppSpec extends Specification with BeforeAllAfterAll{
    sequential
    lazy val app : FakeApplication = {
        FakeApplication()
    }

    def beforeAll(){
        Play.start(app)
    }

    def afterAll(){
        Play.stop()
    }
}
import org.specs2.specification.Step

trait BeforeAllAfterAll extends Specification {
  // see specs2 User Guide, linked below
  override def map(fragments: =>Fragments) = {
    beforeAll()
    fragments ^ Step(afterAll)
  }
    

  def beforeAll()
  def afterAll()
}
```

I think the `map` would be better with `Step(...) ^ fragments ^ Step(...)` but it did not run the beforeAll for me. The [user guide](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Structure.html) at "Global setup/teardown" says to use a lazy val.

Overall it was a pain to set up this. My problem was
`Exception in thread "Thread-145" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset`
Or

`Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]] (Configuration.scala:559)`

When reusing the same FakeApplication:
`SQLException: Attempting to obtain a connection from a pool that has already been shutdown.`

I think it is much more logical this way than always creating a new application for every "in" block or adding all tests into one block.